# Removing values that contain a string using dplyr (R)

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr, contain

My current code removes only the values that have the ***exact*** value of "unassigned", whereas I want it to remove any value that ***contains*** "unassigned".

Here's my code

```
Newdata <- mydata %>%
  filter(taxon !="unassigned")
```

The column I'm looking to remove any "unassigned" values from is called taxon.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using regular expressions. I believe something like `grepl("unassigned", taxon)` should give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grepl answer:

```
Newdata <- mydata %>%
  filter(!grepl(".*unassigned.*",taxon))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
# Create sample data
test <- c("hello", "world", "unassigned", "unassigned2", "unassigned3")
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(test)
# Filter dataframe named "df" at column "test" for strings containing "unassigned"
df %>% filter(str_detect(test, "unassigned"))
```

This outputs

```
         test
1  unassigned
2 unassigned2
3 unassigned3
```